# How to share Minecraft worlds between iPad and PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, ios

I have Minecraft on iPad and am signed into my Microsoft account. I have bought Minecraft on a PS4, and have linked my PSN account to my Microsoft account.

But worlds I created on my iPad do not show up on the PS4. I would have thought that the point on a Microsoft account was that game data could be shared?

How can I share my worlds between these platforms?

Comment: With "share" you mean being able to load the same world on different devices? Worlds are saved locally, MS account is needed only to play online, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh right. So there's no way to move a world between devices? I've read more and maybe I need to buy a realm - would that let me share a world between my devices? I.e I could play on iPad then ps4 then iPad...? Also wondering if setting up my own server might provide a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not expert about setting up servers, but the Realms solution should work. I play Minecraft from PS4 with friends on Switch, Android tablet, Xbox and PC. If the game version on iPad is the same you should be able to do it.